# Prove the following(sets)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$ C \subseteq  A$, $ B \subseteq D $ and $|C \cup D | = |C|  $, than $|A \cup B|=|A|$

I tried many methods without any success, I assume that some kind of induction could help.

-my thoughts with London-

Comment: Are they finite sets or any sets?

Comment: they are any sets

Comment: What is your definition of $\lvert A\rvert=\lvert B\rvert$? Also, maybe you can choose a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably some way to do all these two cases as one, but I just consider the following separate cases:

1. $C$ is finite. Then since $|C \cup D| = |C|$, it must be true that $D \subseteq C$, and since $B \subseteq D $ and $C \subseteq A$ we get by transitivity of $\subseteq$ that $B \subseteq A$, meaning that $A \cup B = A$, and hence $|A \cup B| = |A|$
2. $C$ is not finite. Since $|C \cup D| = |C|$ it must be the case that $|D| \le |C|$. Also, since $C \subseteq A$ we have that $A$ is not finite, and $|C| \le |A|$. Finally, since $B \subseteq D$ we have that $|B| \le |D|$. By transitivity of $\le$, it follows that $|B| \le |A|$. But since $A$ is not finite, that means that $|A \cup B| = |A|$